# Using Spinnaker to deploy apps to AWS EC2 Windows VM's

Tags: spinnaker

Is it currently possible to deploy an application to AWS EC2 VM's? So far I have only seen linux examples.
If the answer is no is this on the roadmap?

Answer (score 1):

We currently don't have anything in our roadmap around deploying Windows VMs on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried this myself, but [here](https://github.com/spinnaker/rosco/blob/master/rosco-web/config/packer/aws-windows-2012-r2.json)'s a packer template for AWS Windows 2012 R2.

Edit: also one for [Windows on Azure](https://github.com/spinnaker/rosco/blob/master/rosco-web/config/packer/azure-windows-2012-r2.json).